# Core framework libraries in same or different solutions?

Tags: .net, architecture

I have a question on how to properly organize a core framework functionality to be shared across different projects.

Suppose I am going to have libraries responsible for things like core `IO` functionality, `Logging`, `Serialization`, `Mailing`, `SocialMedia`, `Queuing`, `Image Processing`, `File Processing`, `Common Services`, etc, etc...

The question is do I make a separate solution for each library and reference it if and when I need this functionality in other projects? Or should I just put all of those libraries in a single solution (separated by projects) and just reference one library in all of my other projects that depend on any of the core functionality?

Comment: Do these core projects reference each other ? Will there be a continuous integration build for each one, or groups of them ? A dedicated team working on them ?

Comment: I would imagine mostly the core projects should be separate, but there might be a couple dependencies here and there I would imagine. No continuous integration builds, also no dedicated team, but quite possible a few developers adding new features at the same time. (or changing existing ones)

Comment: Both are okay, but Microsoft .NET Core switches to the per component approach and also uses NuGet to resolve dependencies.